# How to create a receiver for Event Hub in c# to get messages for a given timespan?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-eventhub

```
using Azure.Messaging.EventHubs.Consumer;
using System.Text;

string connectionString = "";
string eventHubName = "";
string consumerGroup = EventHubConsumerClient.DefaultConsumerGroupName;

await using (var consumerClient = new EventHubConsumerClient(consumerGroup, connectionString, eventHubName))
{
  await foreach (PartitionEvent partitionEvent in consumerClient.ReadEventsAsync())
  {
    string json = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(partitionEvent.Data.Body.ToArray());
    Console.WriteLine(json);
  }
}
```

This currently returns all messages from the eventHub. I only need to get messages from lets say last 1 hour and then stop listening for new ones.

Comment: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/eventhub/Azure.Messaging.EventHubs/samples/Sample05_ReadingEvents.md#read-events-from-a-partition-starting-from-a-specific-date-and-time

you mean this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you @FalcoAlexander, for pointing out in the right direction. I have referred [Read events from a partition, starting from a specific date and time](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/eventhub/Azure.Messaging.EventHubs/samples/Sample05_ReadingEvents.md#read-events-from-a-partition-starting-from-a-specific-date-and-time) and could able to make the below changes to your code which gave me expected results.

- Instead of using `ReadEventsAsync()` I have used `ReadEventsFromPartitionAsync` where I can mention the timeperiod that I wanted.
- For reproducing the same I have considered the time to be 2 minutes but I your case you can take 1 hour.

```
using Azure.Messaging.EventHubs.Consumer;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Text;

string connectionString = "";
string eventHubName = "";
string consumerGroup = EventHubConsumerClient.DefaultConsumerGroupName;


await using (var consumerClient = new EventHubConsumerClient(consumerGroup, connectionString, eventHubName))
{
    DateTimeOffset timesamp = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10)); // In your case this line would be DateTimeOffset timesamp = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromHours(1));
    EventPosition timestamp = EventPosition.FromEnqueuedTime(timesamp);
    using CancellationTokenSource cancellationSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    string partitionId = (await consumerClient.GetPartitionIdsAsync(cancellationSource.Token)).First();

    await foreach (PartitionEvent partitionEvent in consumerClient.ReadEventsFromPartitionAsync(
       partitionId,
        timestamp))
    {
        string json = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(partitionEvent.Data.Body.ToArray());
        Console.WriteLine(json);
    }
}
```

Results:

[image]